# Два слова: хлестче/хлеще

Tags: орфография

Если ли разница между *хлестче* и *хлеще*? Что это слово — *хлёсткий* — вообще значит?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вопрос № 287224**
Очень интересно было увидеть у вас в словарь ***хлестче*** и (разг.) ***хлеще***, учитывая, что эти две формы **не имеют ни малейшего различия в произношении.** Вопрос по поводу того, как это слово все-таки писать: все словарь говорят ***хлестче***, но справочник Лопатина вносит некую путаницу: Буква щ пишется на конце корня в словах и формах с чередованиями ск — щ, ст — щ, напр.: ищу (ср. искать), прощу, прощённый, прощать (ср. простить), вощаной (воск), дощатый (доска), площе (плоский), гуще (густой), проще (простой), **хлеще (от хлёсткий при отсечении согласной к; ср. хлёстче, § 86).**

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Вариант ***хлеще*** зафиксирован **во многих словарях**, среди которых: «Русский орфографический словарь» РАН, «Большой толковый словарь русского языка» под ред. С. А. Кузнецова, «Словарь трудностей русского языка» Н. А. Еськовой, «Орфоэпический словарь русского языка» (10-е изд. М., 2015). Если в орфографическом словаре даны варианты ***хлёстче*** и ***хлеще***, то остальные издания, перечисленные нами, допускают три формы: ***хлёстче, хлестче, хлеще***.

**Ни одна из них не является ошибочной.**

[http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=хлеще](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5)

**[Предложения со словом «хлестче»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5)**

**[Предложения со словом «хлеще»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5)**

Answer (score 2):

**Хлёстче** или **хлестче** от хлестать - то есть бить в прямом или переносном смысле, шутковать про сарказм или цинизм, бить или делать больнее.

**Хлеще** от хлещет через край - избыточнее, больше, чересчур, удалее ~ **лихой**.

> Но Коля Лавцов не сразу разгадал смысл скользкого намека и потому
> вовремя не пришел дружку на помощь, лишь понукал его взглядом, чтоб
> **бил хлестче**, раз уже началось... Л. М. Леонов. Русский лес (1950-1953)

> — А в колхозе что? — Да вишь ли как, — паромщик грубо выругался, — повернулось дело, что вроде в драке, по пьяному делу Павла **стукнули**.
> Это у нас завсегда — чуть что, надо закон обойти, на пьянство валят. А
> **я бы их**, этих пьяных, еще того **хлестче**, — плюнул старик. Ефремов.

> **Цинизм** этой фразы не мог серьезно задеть Южина — он давно привык
> **подшучивать** над смертью и делал это еще **грубее и хлестче**, — его
> покоробило другое, неискоренимое в каждом фронтовике: наземная служба,
> тыловик судит тех, кто сражается в воздухе. Гранин.

> Даром что бабьего пола, а по конскому делу **разбиралась хлеще** иного казака. Шолохов.

> В самой Повести Фирсов изобразил терзания своего двойника **еще хлеще, неистовей**, и так как списать всю **эту чертовщину** автор мог лишь с себя самого, оставалось временно допустить, что так оно и происходило в действительности. Леонов.

> — Это **тенденциозная подборка**! — немедленно объявил господин Паприкаки. Кэнси немедленно взвился: — У нас за вчерашний день **девятьсот писем насчет хлеба**! — заорал он. — И все — вот такого вот содержания, если **не хлеще**! … — Минуточку! — сказал Андрей, повысив голос, и снова хлопнул ладонью по столу. — Дайте говорить мне! А если вам неугодно, выйдите оба в коридор и препирайтесь там… Стругацкие.

Насчет произношения, я стч выговариваю как с'че, а не через Щ. С выговариванием особо нет проблем, borscht варить не обязательно.

Хлёсткий - бойкий, ловкий, шустрый, за**лих**ватский. Хлёсткий юмор - сарказм. Хлёсткая брань. Пересказ словаря Ушакова) ~ резвый, быстрый, лихой, бьющий по больному.